# How to do CRUD operation in Laravel 5.5 using a single view for all operation?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I don't want to create multiple view for create, delete, update. I want to perform on a single view.

for update operation, i want to use model pop up.

Comment: So what is the problem? You can use bootstrap modal and ajax for that

Comment: Em, have you tried something at least? It is just a simple crud....

Comment: I tried, but how to perform multiple action within one form and one URL

Comment: You won't make it with just 1 form, unless it's a very simple model. You will need to use ajax requests. You will have to use jquery to hide/show modals.

Comment: if i use simple model pop up, is it not possible

Comment: Yes, it is possible

Comment: Mayank please give me link, where i can know how to perform all crud opention on single view without using AJAX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look on this example I created:

https://github.com/apsg/user-crud-excercise

It's very simple User entity CRUD example, using almost entirely single view. The only operation done on separate view is the update.

You should be able to easily implement update as a popup - no problem with that.